# How to Assign a value to a variable defined in a string?

Tags: vba, string, ms-access, variables

I have a string which I have used to specify a variable

I have used eval() to check the value of the variable specified in the string eg

```
'these variables change
Dim String1, String2, String3, String4, String5 as String
String2 = "Form1"
String3 = "Listbox1"
String4 = "Listbox2"

'this routine stays the same
Dim String1 as String
String1 = "forms!" & string2 & "." & string3 & ".selected(1)"  
if eval(String1) = True then 'do this...
```

This works fine - I can just change the variables then run the sub below it

but I want to change the value of the variable specified in the string eg:

```
String5 = "forms!" & string2 & "." & string4 & ".selected(1)"
```

I want to set it as true - but I can't work out how eg:

```
String5.value = True
Set String5 = True
```

I want to have a compact sub code I can use in a variety of different places to do the same task but with variable variables.

Thanks

Comment: Well a string will never evaluate to true or false.  You need a boolean value for that...

Comment: and i'm REALLY rusty on access's flavor of vba, but i think it should be something like `string5 = eval(String1)`....but as I stated, `String5` should actually be a boolean value, not actually a string...so you may want to rename it accordingly.

Comment: Thanks - the string is referencing a variable which is Boolean - in this case, a listbox checkbox - so I need a way to change that variable not evaluate the string for this second step :) the first section with the eval() is working fine btw

Comment: Welcome! I posted an answer that I think will help.

Answer (score 0):

Variable variables? You're thinking about PHP, I guess.

There are better ways to do this in VBA. This code:

```
    String1 = "forms!" & string2 & "." & string3 & ".Selected(1)"  
    If Eval(String1) = True Then ...
```

Is more easily written as:

```
    If Forms(string2).Controls(string3).Selected(1) = True Then ...
```

This standard form is much easier to understand and modify.

Regarding this code:

```
    String5.value = True
    Set String5 = True
```

I think what you are trying to do is:

```
    Forms(string2).Controls(string3).Selected(1) = True
```

You can't use `Eval` here, because `Eval` can only return a string or number, not an object references.

Hope this helps.

PS --

Strings in VBA are not objects as they are in other languages. Instead of `String5.value = True`, use:

```
    String5 = True ' changed to "True"
```

In this line of code:

```
    Dim String1, String2, String3, String4, String5 as String
```

You are declaring four Variants and one String. This is a quirk of VBA. If you want all strings, try:

```
    Dim String1 As String, String2 As String, String3 As String, String4 As String, String5 As String
```